# Why is my image quality decreasing when setting the radius and size?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uiimage

I am using the following methods in a UIImage extension to use an image from a URL and displaying it as a UIBarButtonItem. However, when I use the following to adjust the corner radius and size, the quality of the image gets significantly worse. What needs to change to prevent it from decreasing in quality?

```
extension UIImage {

    public func withRoundedCornersAndSetSize(radius: CGFloat? = nil, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let maxRadius = min(size.width, size.height) / 2
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat
        if let radius = radius, radius > 0 && radius <= maxRadius {
            cornerRadius = radius
        } else {
            cornerRadius = maxRadius
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).addClip()
        draw(in: rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `scale`? Wrong scale will lose quality. Also are you growing / shrinking image when you draw it in this rect? A very big image made very small will obviously lose a lot of pixel definition.

Comment: it's a property of a UIImage extension @matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I could resize the UIImage without losing quality using the `resize()` method in the following code. Then, I just used this in the `withRoundedCornersAndSetSize()` method that I had initially asked about.

```
extension UIImage {
   func withRoundedCornersAndSetSize(radius: CGFloat? = nil, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let resizedImage = self.resize(targetSize: targetSize)
        
        let maxRadius = min(resizedImage.size.width, resizedImage.size.height) / 2
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat
        if let radius = radius, radius > 0 && radius <= maxRadius {
            cornerRadius = radius
        } else {
            cornerRadius = maxRadius
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(resizedImage.size, false, resizedImage.scale)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: resizedImage.size)
        UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).addClip()
        draw(in: rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
    
    func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:targetSize).image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
        }
    }
}
```